# Combine or separate tables based on type

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm confused on whether I should combine two tables or leave them separated.

**Many tables:**

> **Item:** ............ ItemID (pk) ............. ItemName .......ItemDescription
>
> **ItemLike:** ..... ItemLikeID (pk) ....... ItemID (fk) ...... UserID (fk)
>
> **ItemBlock:** ... ItemBlockID (pk) .... ItemID (fk) ...... UserID (fk)
>
> **ItemFlag:**...... ItemFlagID (pk) ...... ItemID (fk) ...... UserID (fk)

**Only 2 tables:**

> **Item:** ................ ItemID (pk) ............. ItemName .......ItemDescription
>
> **ItemAction:** ..... ItemActionID (pk) .... ItemID (fk) ...... UserID (fk) .......... ActionType

The former has a good performance but there are many tables, the latter is compact, but slower when querying (check action type). Which is solution better?

Comment: In the second case, you'd probably need a table ItemActionTypes which describes each type (for instance ActionTypeID, ActionTypeDesc).
That being said, I'd probably go for this solution, but both of them seem to be in the third normal form so it will depend on what you need the most.

Comment: @ArlaudAgbePierre: Why do I need that table? `ActionType` field (int type) in `ItemAction` table is enough to determine the action type. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: it helps preserve integrity. Nothing forbids us from adding an entry with an ActionType that doesn't exist here. By enumerating them in another table, you can check the existence of such a type (which wouldn't be a problem in the first solution because there is one table per type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my opinion 2nd option is much better than 1st one as

```
1) While querying you will get all data in single query
2) No need to make join different table when getting data from table.
3) Primary key will be in a single column in a table rather than in all tables.
4) Easy to understand and maintain.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I need to get all user `'like'` item whose id=1, I have to filter ===> slower than solution 1, right?

Comment: Not if you add an index on the ActionType field, which, granted, will make insertions a bit slower.

Comment: @JohanGosh: you can add index on that particular field as Arlaud Agbe Pierre said.